# How can I pass a value from child form to parent form and back?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a parent form first.cs like this

```
public partial class first : Form
{
    public Graph graphi { get; }
    Graph g = new Graph();
    string s1 = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;

        var parser = new Notation3Parser();
        var graph = new Graph();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "RDF files (*.n3)|*.n3";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        string s = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();

                        string w = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString();

                        string Fname = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.ToString();
                        File.Copy(s, Path.Combine(w, Fname), true);

                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                        Win32.AllocConsole();
                        s1 = Path.Combine(w, Fname);

                        showPath.Text = s1;
                        String parentvalueadress = this.s1;
                        showPath.Visible = true;
                        insertNodeButton.Visible = true;
                        delBut.Visible = true;


                        showNodes showNodes1 = new showNodes(s1);
                        g = showNodes1.returngraph();



                        Console.Read();
                        Win32.FreeConsole();


                        this.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void insertNodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addTriple a1 = new addTriple();
        a1.BringToFront();
        a1.ShowDialog();
        g.SaveToFile(this.s1);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delete a1 = new delete();
        a1.BringToFront();
        a1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

in insertNodeButton_Click method I want to pass a value of graph g to the child form that it is code  is like this:

```
public partial class addTriple : Form
{
    Graph gr;
    String childvalueadress;

    private void addTriple_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parser = new Notation3Parser();
        var graph = new Graph();    
        gr = graph;
        parser.Load(graph, childvalueadress);    
    }

    private void subComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (subComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "URI")
        {
            subUriTB.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            subUriTB.Visible = false;
            label1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void objComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((objComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "URI") || (objComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Literal"))
        {
            objUriTB.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            objUriTB.Visible = false;
            label1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void addTripleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (subComboBox.Text.ToString() == "select" || objComboBox.Text.ToString() == "select")
            MessageBox.Show("please select node types");

        else if ((subComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "URI") && (subUriTB.Text.ToString() == ""))
            MessageBox.Show("please fill text box for URI");
        else if ((preUriTB.Text.ToString() == ""))
            MessageBox.Show("please fill text box for URI");
        else if ((objUriTB.Text.ToString() == "") && ((objComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "URI") || (objComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Literal")))
            MessageBox.Show("please fill text box for object name");
        else if ((objComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "URI") && (objUriTB.Text.ToString() == ""))
            MessageBox.Show("please fill text box for URI");
        try
        {
            if ((subComboBox.Text.ToString() == "URI") && (objComboBox.Text.ToString() == "URI"))
                addUUU(subUriTB.Text.ToString(), preUriTB.Text.ToString(), objUriTB.Text.ToString(), gr);
            else if ((subComboBox.Text.ToString() == "URI") && (objComboBox.Text.ToString() == "Literal"))
                addUUL(subUriTB.Text.ToString(), preUriTB.Text.ToString(), objUriTB.Text.ToString(), gr);
            else if ((subComboBox.Text.ToString() == "Blank") && (objComboBox.Text.ToString() == "Literal"))
                addBUL(preUriTB.Text.ToString(), objUriTB.Text.ToString(), gr);
            else if ((subComboBox.Text.ToString() == "URI") && (objComboBox.Text.ToString() == "Blank"))
                addUUB(subUriTB.Text.ToString(), preUriTB.Text.ToString(), gr);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please correct the uri");
        }
        gr.SaveToFile("c:\\n.n3");
    }
}
```

and work with this value in this child form and then pass it to the parent form first.cs

how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you think that such (dirty) formatting is acceptable anywhere in public place?!

Comment: There is at least ∞ questions on this topic on SO. Please search before asking.

Comment: Please update this question if you have any changes or anything to add, **do not** ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and then ask question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for child form

```
// In Parent Form
addTriple a1 = new addTriple();

a1.G = graphicdata //assign graphic data here
a1.BringToFront();
a1.ShowDialog();
g.SaveToFile(this.s1);


// In Child Form
public Graph  G
{
    get { return gr; }
    set { gr = value; }
}
```

now you can have access to this anywere and assign data to it before showing the form

Comment: you mean i write this in child form and i can access to it in my parent form?

Comment: with what  syntax i can access to that in child form?

Comment: addTriple a1 = new addTriple();

a1.G= graphic data

Comment: I edited it,now its more clear

Comment: age inkaro bokoni nabayad moshkeli bashe baradar ya khahar jan!

Comment: baradare gerami mamnon   in graphicdata ke inja gozashti yani che?

Comment: Ok,it means you should set the value you are goingto pass to child window here

Comment: i do that it's work    mamnon

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible approaches to this. One is to hold a reference to the parent form within the child form. Or the other is to add a property to the child form.

**Reference**

Add a member variable to the addTriple class which is of type first

e.g.

```
first _parent;
```

Change the constructor on the addTriple form to the following

```
    public addTriple(first p, Graph g)
    {
        _parent = p;
        this.Graph = g; //now you have a reference to the graph from the original form.
    }
```

When displaying the new form use the following code:

```
addTriple a1 = new addTriple(this, g); //g being the graph you wish to use in the modal form.
a1.BringToFront();
a1.ShowDialog();
```

**Property**

To the addTriple class add a property

```
public Graph Graph {get;set;}
```

Then to display the form use the following

```
addTriple a1 = new addTriple(); //create a new instance of the form
a1.Graph = this.Graph; //set the graph to the one from the parent form
a1.ShowDialog(); //show the form as a dialog
this.Graph = a1.Graph; // once the form is closed get the changed graph back to the parent.
```

Comment: how should i pass data from child to parent?

Comment: see the amended answer for an example of how this can be achieved

Comment: ok i do it but it get error from this line    this.Parent = parent;   what should i do now

Comment: I have amended the code since that error as a form has a Parent property. Try amending your code to the above. It should fix it.

Comment: This is not the OO way, DeveloperX has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

//// Make a Constructor like this for addTriple form and pass Graph object as referance

```
  public addTriple(ref Graph g)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//can access g here ......

        }
```

then call it like this from main form

```
    private void insertNodeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                addTriple a1 = new addTriple(ref g);
                a1.BringToFront();
                a1.ShowDialog();
               //New g will be available here
                g.SaveToFile(this.s1);

            }
```

don't know whether this is best method or not

Comment: ok how can i do it visa versa pass a value from child to parent?

Comment: @ghasedak edited my answer please check it